# Add help text to checkbox options on node form

Tags: forms

How can I add help text to each option on checkbox option on drupal node form. I do not want to add this from UI while adding values for the field. Using hook_form_alter I do not believe we have option to add description to options of a checkbox field.

Example: "which game you want to play" is the checkbox field.

which game you want to play?

[] cricket

-- cricket is awesome.

[] football

-- football is more than awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do this first by overriding checkboxes theme hook **theme_checkboxes($var)** with preprocess hook **template_preprocess_checkboxes($var)** but there was not any option to set *#suffix* property to individual checkbox, Then i figured out that **theme_checkboxes** theme hook call the **theme_checkbox** hook for individual checkbox then i tried to override **theme_checkbox($var)** with **template_preprocess_checkbox($var)** but that also didn't worked, I was able to set *#suffix* and *#field_suffix* property on individual checkbox but that was not rendering because individual checkbox's *#processed* property was already set to True, I tried by setting that *false* but no success :(

I tried by setting **pre_render** callback and **process** callback but too didn't worked, May be i was making some mistake.

This is preprocess hook for checkboxes theme hook:

```
function template_preprocess_checkboxes($variables) {
  $variables['element']['element_name']['#printed'] = FALSE;
  $variables['element']['element_name']['#processed'] = FALSE;
  $variables['element']['element_name']['#suffix'] = 'This is help text';
  $variables['element']['element_name']['#pre_render'][] = 'mymodule_checkbox';

  $element = $variables['element'];
  $attributes = array();
  if (isset($element['#id'])) {
    $attributes['id'] = $element['#id'];
  }
  $attributes['class'][] = 'form-checkboxes';
  if (!empty($element['#attributes']['class'])) {
    $attributes['class'] = array_merge($attributes['class'], $element['#attributes']['class']);
  }
  if (isset($element['#attributes']['title'])) {
    $attributes['title'] = $element['#attributes']['title'];
  }
  return '<div' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . (!empty($element['#children']) ? $element['#children'] : '') . '</div>';
}

function mymodule_checkbox($var){
  $var['element']['#suffix'] = 'this is help text added by pre render callback';
}
```

Then i tried the same with template_preprocess_checkbox($var)

```
function template_preprocess_checkbox($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'checkbox';

  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', '#return_value' => 'value'));

  if ($variables['element']['#parents'][0] == 'parent_field_name') {
    $variables['element']['#attributes']['#processed'] = FALSE;
    $variables['element']['#attributes']['#field_suffix'] = t('This is simple help text');
    $variables['element']['#suffix'] = 'another suffix';        
  }

  // Unchecked checkbox has #value of integer 0.
  if (!empty($element['#checked'])) {
    $element['#attributes']['checked'] = 'checked';
  }
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-checkbox'));

  return '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';
}
```

Can someone help me too on this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
function yourmodulename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 if($form_id == 'yourformid') {
   $form['your_checkbox_field'] = array(
     '#field_suffix' => t('Field help text.')
   );
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks Arun, I need to have help text with checkbox options not with the field. With the above code it will add the help text with the field.

Comment: could you please provide a screenshot, about how you want to show the help text.

Comment: check the example mentioned where "which game you want to play?" is the field where cricket and football are options a user can check and below them are the help text I want to add.

Comment: did you try both `#field_suffix` and `#suffix`?

Comment: Arun I am very sure they are supposed to work with field not with options